# Select rows in left join which depend on sum of a field in the other table?

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery, left-join, aggregate-functions

Im trying to write a SQL left outer join query where the left rows are selected based on the sum of a field in rows in the other (right) table. The other table has an id field that links back to the left table and there is a one-to-many relationship between left and right tables. The tables (simplified to relevant fields only) look like this:

left_table:

```
+--------+
| id     |
| amount |
+--------+
```

right_table:

```
+-------------------+
| id                |
| amount            |
| left_table_row_id |
+-------------------+
```

Basically the right table's rows' amount fields have fractions of the amounts in the left table and are associated back to the `left_table`, so several `right_table` rows might be linked to a single `left_table` row.

Im trying to select only `left_table` rows where `left_table.id=right_table_id` **and** where the *sum of the amounts* in the `right_table`'s rows with linked id are equal to `left_table.amount`. We can't use aggregate in a WHERE clause and I had no luck with using HAVING. I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter with a correlated subquery:

```
select l.*
from left_table l
where l.amount = (select sum(r.amount) from right_table r where r.id = l.id)
```

Comment: That's a lot simpler than any join :-) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible with the following query:

```
with agg as
(
    select left_table_row_id,sum(amount) as amount
    from right_table
    group by left_table_row_id
)
select *
from left_table lt
where exists (select 1 from agg where lt.id=agg.left_table_row_id and lt.amount = agg.amount)
```